# What is the purpose of the spider egg hat?

Tags: magicite

In Magicite, there is a special hat that you can begin with, which is the spider egg hat.

The hat has a 10% chance to spawn a broodmother any time you get hit, but the spawned broodmother is hostile against you, so what is the use of this hat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spider egg hat has no other purpose than the one you mentioned, which is to spawn a hostile spider egg 10% of the time. I will quote the Magicite wiki here on their article about hats:

> "Its hard to keep up with the fashion in Deephaven. One not so popular trend is to put a Broodmother's Egg on top of your head despite it being very dangerous."

They have good reason for this! The hat is not popular due to it being potentially harmful.

Source: http://magicite.wikia.com/wiki/Hats

Answer (score 1):

The Eggs can be used to farm exp to reach level 40 if you dont get hit long enough to gear up and farm exp.